# Using bitbake to build a custom gumstix kernel

Tags: gumstix

I've a gumstix Overo which I am configuring to work with a e-CAM camera. The documentation provided by camera manufacture asks me to patch a 2.6.34 kernel and compile in Video For Linux support. When I look at [gumstix user documentation](http://www.gumstix.net/wiki/index.php?title=Kernel_Reconfiguration) they say I should execute:

```
bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/linux
```

However when I run this command I get

```
bacon:~/proj/overo-oe$ bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/linux
NOTE: Handling BitBake files: \ (7100/7100) [100 %]
NOTE: Parsing finished. 6382 cached, 413 parsed, 305 skipped, 2 masked.
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'virtual/linux'
```

I'm not altogether sure about how I provide virtual/linux. Any ideas about how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a case of out-of-date documentation. In any case, my current work around is to name the kernel explicitly: bitbake -c menuconfig linux-omap3-2.6.34

Answer (score 0):

I can help with a step-by-step procedure to bitbake 3.0 kernel.
If that may be helpful for you. Using a WMware Ubuntu ...

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from convoluted build systems as bitbake. Every one seems to be inventing one... making the 'tool' to get more of your time then the thing you want to do with the tool. All of them are the same. Linus would quote on those guys: 
Just don't do it...!